Dotnet8-isolated Mac Visual studio 2022 - Not able to run Azure functions
Before I was working on Windows and I switched to Mac.
I am trying to setup project with Azure functions and run it locally.
I am getting error "Cannot execute "path.functionname.exe"
Cannot execute exe
All nuget packages are upto date and restored. I tried to clean bin folder - unsuccessful
.Net SDK version 8
func - version 4.0.3687
SDK version
Settings of the project:
trigger:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace SchedulesFunction.Triggers
{
    public class SchedulesTrigger
    {
        [Function("SchedulesTrigger")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}

.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="Configuration\" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="local.settings.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Configuration\" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>


Program.cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();


local.settings.json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
 }

I tried to update SDK version
I changed the settings to always use 8 SDK if available
Nothing works. I can't run the azure functions locally on mac
UPDATE
The solution

Check if Azurite is installed:

ps aux | grep azurite

Install/Update Azurite:

npm install -g azurite

Run Azurite:

azurite --silent

Get azure-functions newest version:

brew tap azure/functions
brew install azure-functions-core-tools@4

Update Visual Studio:
Visual studio -> New Project -> Check if cloud project is available

a) If not available:
open any project -> Visual Studio (top bar) -> Check for Updates -> Update all packages (the Cloud project should be available now)
b) If available:
Cloud -> Azure Functions -> Check what Runtime is available
-In my case only .Net Core 3.1 was available
Run -> Check Templates for update -> App Restart
-After that .Net 7.0 isolated was available as. The highest possible version
Finally I gave up with Visual studio and  I switched to Visual Studio Code and in launch.json file:
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    
    {
        "name": "Attach to .NET Functions",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:azureFunctions.pickProcess}"
    }
]

}

The .NET 8 SDK was not downloaded properly on your system. Follow this link to download the .NET SDK for macOS and check the path. After completing the installation process, make sure to restart your Visual Studio.
I tried the sample Timer trigger function below.
Code :
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp109
{
    public class SchedulesTrigger
    {
        private readonly ILogger<SchedulesTrigger> _logger;
        public SchedulesTrigger(ILogger<SchedulesTrigger> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }
        [Function("SchedulesTrigger")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */4 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Timer trigger function ran successfully at : {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}

Program.cs :
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

.csproj :
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Output :
The Timer trigger function ran successfully as follows.


I reinstalled the .Net SDK and still same issue. How does your Program.cs looks like?

How about the Target Framework? My shows me: Project Properties -> Build -> General
Target Framework (.Net 8.0). In local.settings.json "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated".

@A P I have the same local.settings.json file as your's.

On Windows the project works perfectly. It must be some mac Visual studio configuration

@A P Can you try to uninstall.Net 8 SDK and follow this link to download it in macOS.

@A P Check this link to run Functions triggers in Visual studio in macOS.

Can you confirm that, are you able to run other triggers like HTTP trigger function etc.

Please note that the .NET 8 support in Visual Studio for Mac is still in preview and some things may not work or be fully implemented.
I have tried to enable .net8 as preview feature but it does not help. Workaround is to start your function with command line 'func host start'.

Appreciate the heads-up! Seems like relying on 'func host start' is a viable workaround given the current .NET 8 preview limitations in Visual Studio for Mac.
